# how to convert json to object, like CQRS design pattern

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, cqrs

I have a problem where I need to convert json to C # object. but this json can have different properties that make when converting it is necessary to check whether the object is valid or not like using a switch case.

I saw in CQRS the design pattern seems to have something in common, does anyone know how it works? so that I can implement it.

```
     public List<Event> process(CreateOrderCommand cmd) {
    return EventUtil.events(new OrderCreatedEvent(cmd.getCustomerId(), cmd.getOrderTotal()));
  }

  public List<Event> process(ApproveOrderCommand cmd) {
    return EventUtil.events(new OrderApprovedEvent(customerId));
  }

  public List<Event> process(RejectOrderCommand cmd) {
    return EventUtil.events(new OrderRejectedEvent(customerId));
  }
```

as you can see all the method names are the same but the parameters are different. I want to implement this so that when I get json it will be converted according to a valid object.

what i have done currently:

```
      public bool TryParseJson<T>(string @this, out T result)
    {
        bool success = true;
        var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
        {
            Error = (sender, args) => { success = false; args.ErrorContext.Handled = true; },
            MissingMemberHandling = MissingMemberHandling.Error
        };
        result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(@this, settings);
        return success;
    }

    public void Process(JObject query)
    {
        RandomUser randomUser;
        RecurringProcess recurringProcess;
        if (TryParseJson(query.ToString(), out randomUser))
        {
            //do something with the object
        }
        else if (TryParseJson(query.ToString(), out recurringProcess))
        {
            //do something with the object
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this has anything to do with CQRS. If you want to be sure you're constructing a valid object use Newtonsoft.JSON's functionality to deserialize your JSON using a constructor with parameters. Tailor the constructor of your object to your needs, so you can guarantee yourself you're always constructing a valid object.
If there are validation errors throw the necessary exceptions and catch them along the way.

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest you using schemas. You can create a JSON schema and validate JSON files against that schema using JSON.Net, something like that:

```
JsonSchema schema = JsonSchema.Parse(jsonSchema);
JObject obj = JObject.Parse(jsonString);
bool valid = obj.IsValid(schema);
```

So, you can do something like this according to your need.

```
// initialize this dictionary somewhere which maps schemas to command classes
Dictionary<JsonSchema, CommandBaseClass> jsonSchemaToCommandMapping;

public CommandBaseClass FindCommand(string @this, out DeserializeObjectsBaseType result)
{
    // loop through schemas in the jsonSchemaToCommandMapping
    // to find out which command class to use

    return calculatedCommand;
}

public void Process(JObject query)
{
    var commandClass = FindCommand(query.ToString(), out DeserializeObjectsBaseType deserializeObject);
    // remember to check if command is null. maybe it was not found
    commandClass?.Process(deserializeObject);
}
```

But please remember that this example I quickly made is short and not the prettiest.
It's just to show you my idea.

Comment: what does the findCommand do? and what is CommandBaseClass ?

Comment: I'm sorry my example was wrong. the FindCommand function is the 1st function in the example. I added some comments about what it should do.
It will loop through schemas in the jsonSchemaToCommandMapping and return the correct command class. Every json schema has it's corresponding command class, so here the correct command class means the class which you should select for the specific schema. CommandBaseClass is the base class for all the Command classes you have. Ex. CreateOrderCommand, ApproveOrderCommand etc. it will be the base class for these.